# How to send navigation params to a test

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to make a test of a subscribe function, but I'm new with Jest and tests and I can't find a solution. Here's the situation:

This subscribe form is in 2 parts, the first one is sending datas to the second one.

My question is, how can I set default params from react-navigation on my test (of the second form) ?

Maybe you will understand better with the code :

Result of my test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParam' of undefined

    > 33 |       lastName: navigation.getParam('lastName', undefined),
```

My test:

```
describe('checking datas', () => {
  it('checking good datas', () => {
    const formUser = {
      birthday: '17/07/1992',
      country: 'France',
      refGolf: 'Bruges',
    };
    const datas = renderer.create(<SubscribeNext />).getInstance();

    expect(datas.checkValues(
      formUser.birthday,
      formUser.country,
      formUser.refGolf,
    )).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

my first form is sending datas:

```
  toSubscribeNext() {
    const {
      navigation
    } = this.props;
    const {
      lastName,
      firstName,
      email,
      username,
      password,
      passwordCheck
    } = this.state;

    if (this.checkValues(lastName, firstName, email, username, password, passwordCheck)) {
      navigation.navigate('SubscribeNext', {
        lastName,
        firstName,
        email,
        username,
        password
      });
    }
  }
```

my second form is getting them:

```
export default class Subscribe extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { navigation } = props;
    this.state = {
      lastName: navigation.getParam('lastName', undefined),
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - in your first from :

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('SubscribeNext', { lastName: this.state.lastName, ... })}
```

2 - and in your second form :

receiving props using componentWillReceiveProps  and update state

```
...
    this.state = {lastName:''};
      ....
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.navigation.state.params.lastName) {
          this.setState({lastName:nextProps.navigation.state.params.lastName});
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

use in your second from

```
this.state = {
  name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name
.
.
.
    }
```

and in your first form :

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('screen name', { email: this.state. email, name: name, ... })}
```

Comment: I got the same problem, my test of the second form doesn't get the params of the first form: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    > 33 |       lastName: navigation.state.params.lastName,

Comment: Try to set recieved props in ComponentWillReciveProps function (its a life cycle func)